# Android - Fragment view OnKey method not called when there is more than an item

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I don't understand this: I have a ListFragment which must show a list of products and categories, when I enter a category a TextView over the list should show the actual category. I also need the back button to go back to the root category.
The OnKey works when in the layout I have just the ListView

```
  <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
```

When i add the TextView to show the category OnKey is not called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Fragment code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_cats, container, false);
        //actual_category_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actual_category_name);
        view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
```

Changing the ListFragment to fragment doesen't change anything.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think maybe the Activity is consuming the back press. Place a log statement in your Activity's onBackPressed() callback to see fi it's being printed. You could make your own onBackPressed() in your Fragment and have the Activity call to it. Make that method return a boolean so that if it does nothing, you can have the Activity do it's normal processing for back presses.

Comment: I don't istantiate fragment in my activity because it's a tabbed one.